# Viewing multiple queries at once once they finish loading in php code igniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using code igniter and in my view I have three methods that call their respective controller method which loads data coming from the database. I am calling all these methods at once in a seperate function. The problem I am having is that some methods show at different times. Is there a way I can implement it where all three functions show their data at the same time once the last function finishes loading?
This is what I currently have

```
function function1()
 {  
    $("#container1").load("/method1/"); 
 }
 function function2()
 {  
    $("#container2").load("/method2/"); 
 }
 function function3()
 {  
    $("#container3").load("/method3/"); 
 }
```

And this is the main function where it calls all of those 3 functions

```
function callall()
{
  function1();
  function2();
  function3();
}
```

Comment: Why would this have anything to do with codeigniter?

Comment: because there is always someone asking for it. If you don't have any insight regarding this question, Please don't respond

Answer (score 0):

`load` accepts a completed callback. You can hide all your elements, then only show them after that callback is called 3 times.

Edit: code

```
$("#container1").load("/method1/", handleCompleted); // put handleCompleted in all 3

completedCount = 0
function handleCompleted() { completedCount++; if(completedCount == 3) showAll() }
```

Comment: I know I can do something like this
`$( "#container" ).load(url, function() {
     // do something
    });` but for three functions how? Do I just do that three times and then call my functions?

Comment: I don't think that is going to work. Those three containers don't exists until I press a button which calls the function showall() which calls all those 3 functions. If I use your methods. function 1, 2 and 3 never get call

Answer (score 0):

Instead

```
function function1()
 {  
       return   data1;
 }
 function function2()
 {  
       return   data2;

 }
 function function3()
 {  
   return   data3;
 }


function callall()
{
  $data[1] =function1();
  $data[2] = function2();
  $data[3] = function3();
  $data['container3'] = $this->load->view('view', $data, TRUE);
}
```

actual code may differ.